# How to trigger a new state in a timed state machine (solidity)

Tags: solidity

I am creating a perpetual trivia dapp (for learning purposes) that has 3 stages. Each stage should last approximately 30 secs. Example:

```
enum Stages {
    AcceptingEntryFees,
    RevealQuestion,
    Complete
}

modifier transitionToReveal(uint _playerCount) {
    _;
    if (stage == Stages.AcceptingEntryFees && now >= creationTime + 30 seconds && _playerCount > 0) {
        nextStage();
    }
}

modifier transitionToComplete() {
    _;
    if (stage == Stages.RevealQuestion && now >= creationTime + 60 seconds) {
        nextStage();
    }
}

modifier transitionToAcceptingFees() {
    _;
    if (stage == Stages.Complete && now >= creationTime + 90 seconds) {
        nextStage();
    }
}

function nextStage() internal {
    stage = Stages(uint(stage) + 1);
}
```

Im struggling with a solution on how to make the stage increment once the time requirement has been met. I don't need exactly 30 seconds by any means.

Take the first transition (accepting fees).

```
function payEntryFee() external payable transitionToReveal(getPlayerCount()) atStage(Stages.AcceptingEntryFees) {
    ....
}
```

I currently have it set up where people can pay to play up until the 30 seconds is up. However for the stage to increment a tx has to take place. So for this setup the first person to join after the 30 seconds is up will incur the gas price and trigger the next stage. This is not ideal because what if another player doesn't show for a while.

From my research there is no way to trigger a method internally by time and trying to trigger it from the front end would require gas and then who pays it?

Can anyone think of an elegant solution to this? I would like the stage to increment every ~ 30 seconds without interruption to the game.

Answer (score 1):

You would either need an external entity, like a game master web application which changes the state using its own timer and sending transactions but that would cost you gas for every single transaction.

Or you could keep track of the state on the front end (kind of like syncing) and then whenever the player interacts with the ethereum dapp to make a function call, you could do a fetchState() to get the new state and then route the player to the correct game state.

For example, after the web app frontend gets confirmation that the user has paid, it personally keeps track of the state and presents the user with the UI options related to predicted state of the dapp, then when the user sends something like "submitTriviaAnswer" the dapp would update its state and verify that the user can submit a trivia answer.

```
function SubmitTriviaAnswer(int responseID) public {

    fetchState()

    ...

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I definatley think that solution would work however I'm researching common patterns in the solidity docs http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/common-patterns.html#state-machine and I think this would break the pattern due to trying to call a function that is not part of the current stage.